# Python3 using f-string with regex in findall

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, findall, f-string

I tried to use re.findall to look for some string to parse to information I want to pattern from a large html file. the information I need is **0000-01-02-03-04-asdasdad** that sit in the string like **https://xxx/yyy/0000-01-02-03-04-asdasdad/index.css**
How can I do it?

```
def func(html: str):
  import re
  pattern = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\w+'
  s = fr'https://xxx/yyy/{pattern}/index.css'
  return re.findall(s, html)
  # error: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: Can you check the type of the html variable immediately after it is passed in?

Comment: No....It's HTML file..Just punch of text

Comment: You can't check the type after it's passed in? What's keeping you from doing that?

Comment: what do you mean check the "type"?

Comment: Just put `print(type(html))` as the first line of your function.

Comment: thank you. it turns out i need to decode my input.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a good day.